# Нестабильно работает отправка запросов в Volley

Tags: android, android-volley

Приложение довольно часто отправляет и принимает запросы от сервера. Раньше делал все при помощи DefaultHttpClient и работало замечательно, но решил перейти на Volley и есть большая проблема. После примерно 30 запросов перестает вообще отправлять и принимать их. В LogCat пусто. Сделал singleton для RequestQueue. Используется VolleyPlus.

Инициализация singleton в Application

```
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    //Init Volley requests
    StringRequest.getInstance(this);
    ...
     }
```

Сам класс

```
public class StringRequest {
private final String TAG = this.getClass().getSimpleName();
private static StringRequest mInstance;
private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;
private ProgressListener mProgress;
private ResponseListener mResponse;
private ErrorListener mError;
private List<String> files;

private StringRequest(Context context){
    mRequestQueue = getRequestQueue(context.getApplicationContext());
}

public static synchronized StringRequest getInstance(Context context)
{
    if (null == mInstance)
        mInstance = new StringRequest(context);
    return mInstance;
}

public static synchronized StringRequest getInstance()
{
    if (null == mInstance)
    {
        throw new IllegalStateException(StringRequest.class.getSimpleName() +
                " is not initialized, call getInstance(...) first");
    }
    return mInstance;
}

public RequestQueue getRequestQueue(Context context) {
    if (mRequestQueue == null) {
        mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context, getStack());
    }
    return mRequestQueue;
}

private HurlStack getStack(){
    return new HurlStack() {
        @Override
        protected HttpURLConnection createConnection(URL url) throws IOException {
            HttpsURLConnection httpsURLConnection = (HttpsURLConnection) super.createConnection(url);
            try {
                httpsURLConnection.setSSLSocketFactory(getSSLSocketFactory());
                httpsURLConnection.setHostnameVerifier(getHostnameVerifier());
            } catch (CertificateException | KeyStoreException | KeyManagementException | NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "getHurlStack ", e);
            }
            return httpsURLConnection;
        }
    };
}

public void createRequest(String tag, String url, Map<String, String> params){
    final SimpleMultiPartRequest request = new SimpleMultiPartRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    //Log.d(TAG, response);
                    if(mResponse != null)
                        mResponse.onResponse(response);
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            //Log.d(TAG, error.getMessage());
            if(mError != null)
                mError.onError(error);
        }
    }) {
        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            SharedPreferences app_preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(Application.getInstance());
            HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("PARAM1", app_preferences.getString("user", ""));
            params.put("PARAM2", app_preferences.getString("password", ""));
            return params;
        }
    };
    if(getFiles()!=null && getFiles().size()>0) {
        for(int i=0; i<getFiles().size(); i++) {
            request.addFile("images", getFiles().get(i));
        }
    }
    request.setFixedStreamingMode(true);
    request.setTag(tag);
    /*request.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(20 * 1000, 0,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));*/
    request.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(20 * 1000, 1, 1.0f));
    request.setShouldCache(false);
    if(params!=null && params.size()>0){
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : params.entrySet()) {
            request.addStringParam(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
        }
    }
    request.setOnProgressListener(new Response.ProgressListener() {
        int latestPercentDone, percentDone;
        @Override
        public void onProgress(long transferredBytes, long totalSize) {
            latestPercentDone = (int) ((transferredBytes / (float) totalSize) * 100);
            if (percentDone != latestPercentDone) {
                percentDone = latestPercentDone;
                if(mProgress != null)
                    mProgress.onProgress(percentDone);
            }
        }
    });

    mRequestQueue.add(request);
}

private HostnameVerifier getHostnameVerifier() {
    return new HostnameVerifier() {
        @Override
        public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
            HostnameVerifier hv = HttpsURLConnection.getDefaultHostnameVerifier();
            return hv.verify("mysite.com", session);
        }
    };
}

private TrustManager[] getWrappedTrustManagers(TrustManager[] trustManagers) {
    final X509TrustManager originalTrustManager = (X509TrustManager) trustManagers[0];
    return new TrustManager[]{
            new X509TrustManager() {
                public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                    return originalTrustManager.getAcceptedIssuers();
                }

                public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
                    try {
                        if (certs != null && certs.length > 0){
                            certs[0].checkValidity();
                        } else {
                            originalTrustManager.checkClientTrusted(certs, authType);
                        }
                    } catch (CertificateException e) {
                        Log.w(TAG, e.toString());
                    }
                }

                public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
                    try {
                        if (certs != null && certs.length > 0){
                            certs[0].checkValidity();
                        } else {
                            originalTrustManager.checkServerTrusted(certs, authType);
                        }
                    } catch (CertificateException e) {
                        Log.w(TAG, e.toString());
                    }
                }
            }
    };
}

private SSLSocketFactory getSSLSocketFactory()
        throws CertificateException, KeyStoreException, IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyManagementException {
    CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
    InputStream caInput = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("res/raw/cert.bks");

    //Certificate ca = cf.generateCertificate(caInput);

    KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("BKS");
    keyStore.load(caInput, "password".toCharArray());
    //keyStore.setCertificateEntry("ca", ca);
    caInput.close();

    String tmfAlgorithm = TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm();
    TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(tmfAlgorithm);
    tmf.init(keyStore);

    TrustManager[] wrappedTrustManagers = getWrappedTrustManagers(tmf.getTrustManagers());

    SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
    sslContext.init(null, wrappedTrustManagers, null);

    return sslContext.getSocketFactory();
}

public List<String> getFiles() {
    return files;
}

public void setFiles(List<String> files) {
    this.files = files;
}

public void setProgressListener(ProgressListener mProgress) {
    this.mProgress = mProgress;
}

public void setResponseListener(ResponseListener mResponse) {
    this.mResponse = mResponse;
}

public void setErrorListener(ErrorListener mError) {
    this.mError = mError;
}

public interface ResponseListener{
    void onResponse(String response);
}

public interface ErrorListener{
    void onError(VolleyError error);
}

public interface ProgressListener{
    void onProgress(int percent);
}
```

}

И далее я его использую, например в Activity:

```
try{
                Map<String, String> mParams = new HashMap<>();
                mParams.put("lat", String.valueOf(params[0]));
                mParams.put("lon", String.valueOf(params[1]));
                final CountDownLatch countDownLatch = new CountDownLatch(1);
                final Object[] responseHolder = new Object[1];
                StringRequest request = StringRequest.getInstance();
                request.setResponseListener(new StringRequest.ResponseListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        responseHolder[0] = response;
                        countDownLatch.countDown();
                    }
                });
                request.setErrorListener(new StringRequest.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onError(VolleyError error) {
                        responseHolder[0] = error;
                        countDownLatch.countDown();
                    }
                });
                request.createRequest(TAG, URL, mParams);
                try {
                    countDownLatch.await();
                }catch (InterruptedException e){
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
                if(responseHolder[0] instanceof VolleyError){
                    VolleyError volleyError = (VolleyError)responseHolder[0];
                    Log.e(getClass().getName(), volleyError.toString());
                }else{
                    String response = (String)responseHolder[0];
                    try {
                        JSONObject mJson = new JSONObject(response);
                        try {
                            if (mJson.getString("status").equals("OK")) {
                                try {
                                    User user = AppSettings.getmUser();
                                    user.setHomeLat(Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(params[0])));
                                    user.setHomeLon(Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(params[1])));
                                    AppSettings.setmUser(user);
                                    Log.i(getClass().getName(), "Get location: " + String.valueOf(params[0]) + ":" + String.valueOf(params[1]));
                                    return true;
                                }catch(Exception ex){
                                    Log.e(this.getClass().getSimpleName(), "Double convert Exception", e);
                                }
                            } else if (mJson.getString("status").equals("BAD")) {
                                Log.i(getClass().getName(), "Error " + mJson.getInt("statusCode") + " " + mJson.getString("message"));
                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            Log.e(getClass().getName(), "JSON Exception1", e);
                            throw e;
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }catch(Exception e){
                this.e = e;
            }
```

Если перестать использовать singleton, то работает отлично, но Volley хранит все запросы в памяти https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25868608/volley-framewok-request-keeps-objects-in-memory и возникает зависание приложения через примерно полдня интенсивной работы.

Comment: Если есть возможность и ещё не поздно, переключитесь на Retrofit 2.

Retrofit 2 - замечательная библиотека от Square, которая очень помогает создавать и управлять запросами по API.

* Retrofit сделает сам отдельный поток.
* Значительно сокращается длина кода при разработке
* Динамически строит запросы
* Автоматически конвертирует JSON в объекты (через GSON)
* Обрабатывает ошибки
* Умеет передавать файлы
* имеет OkHttp для прямой работы с верхним уровнем сокетов Java.

Comment: Если не затруднит, можете дать ссылку на примеры. Особенно меня интересует работа через SSL используя провайдер BKS.

Comment: Без проблем. Сам ретрофит https://square.github.io/retrofit/
Работа с SSL https://www.google.com.ua/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#safe=active&q=retrofit+2+square+ssl

Надеюсь, это поможет вам. Удачи!

Comment: К сожалению мне не подойдет Retrofit, т.к. мне не нужно сразу преобразовывать ответ сервера в объекты и придется переписывать почти весь REST на сервере да и код у меня получился довольно большим для простого запроса без параметров. Буду пробовать при помощи okHttp.